# Don't understand this "NameError: name 'self' is not defined" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the same error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in 
>   my_wallet.checkBalance(self) NameError: name 'self' is not defined

```
balance = 0
def intro():
    global balance
    balance = int(input("How much would you like to start with? No more than 200£! ")
    if balance > 200:
        print("I said less than 200£!")
        intro()
class wallet:
    def __init__(self,money,broke):
        self.broke = False
        self.money = balance
    def checkBalance(self):
        self.money = balance
        print(balance)
    def noCash(self):
        if balance <= 0:
            print("You're done! No more £££!"
        self.broke = True
```

Comment: Is this how you *indented* your program?

Comment: Yes,  here is a pastebin if this would  help so you can see clearer. https://pastebin.com/ZrKGFpMH

Comment: `my_wallet.checkBalance(self)` This line doesn't appear in the code you posted.

Comment: In the pastebin copy, your `checkBalance` has no `self` parameter.

Comment: It is now, I was messing around before I posted it in the pastebin and forgot to add it, but it makes no difference if it's in `checkBalance` or not.

Comment: The indentation in the pastebin code and posted in your question here is **not** the same. The line number in traceback also doesn't match the code in either place. Please [edit] your question and make it a MCVE. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Re-wrote the code from scratch, I hope I did it right this time with the indentation on the post x)

Comment: how are you calling `my_wallet.checkBalance(self)`? it's missing, please add. If you are doing `my_wallet = wallet()` later you only need to call `my_wallet.checkBalance()` without `self`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the exception it seems that you have tried to call `my_wallet.checkBalance` passing `self` as parameter.

Try to do `my_wallet.checkBalance()` instead of `my_wallet.checkBalance(self)`

`self` parameter is passed automatically to class methods in python

Comment: It does not work, I still get the same error

Comment: could you post the rest of the code?

Comment: That's all of the code mate, I just can't wrap my head around the problem and I'm getting lots of down votes :/

Comment: Where it's called for the first time the intro()?

Comment: `intro()` is used if the input the user gives is over 200.
for example the user inputs 201 and `intro()` runs again until the user inputs a valid value

Comment: yes, i got that part. I mean, `intro()` is called by something it you won't even ask you the input. At this point, if this is the entire file, i guess that this file is imported somewhere in your code. Can you post the full traceback of this exception so i can help you more?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/w3erFU2x @alec

Comment: my_wallet is not instantiated, when you create it in the shell, you should do something like `my_wallet = wallet(money=10, broke=False)`

Comment: but the thing is, how do I make it take the value of `balance`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nhHBP70d, but this is not related to this question anymore

Comment: thank you for helping me out mate!